# Text clustering using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, text, cluster-analysis

I've got a text file which looks like this:

```
leave messages 
enterrement de vie de garçon 
sacré coeur 
paris skyline 
singer montmartre girl audience joined man singing playing guitar front tourists 
paris skyline 
paris skyline
```

Each row of this text file corresponds to a document, which I want to cluster using either tf-idf with cosine similarity, or agglomerative clustering. I'm using MATLAB. I've removed the stop words, and punctuation marks.

My issue is that there are 300k of these rows (documents). So scaling is one issue. Another issue is that I'm having trouble understanding how to convert each row of text into a vector of values? Can anybody explain please, with an example?

Thanks.

I tried using k-means clustering (nltk library python) and ran out of memory. Also with k-means I don't have a clue how many clusters I'm supposed to get (so I was just guessing wildly).

Another thing: I have ground truth available for this text (like, I have 0,1,2 labels in another file for this data). And I also have test data (another text file). I'm confused as to how to use this information to help cluster the test data.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Use sparse matrices. Without those, you're going to get stuck really fast if you want to do text processing. That's about all I can say, as I don't use Matlab myself.

Comment: k-means isn't really that useful if you don't know the number of clusters a priori. If you have ground truth data you should probably be using a [supervised learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning) method (k-means is unsupervised).

Comment: Try using a graph clustering algorithm such as RNSC or MCL. They scale well and fit the data (high-dimensional, sparse) well.